# Applying `TrigToExp` only for terms containing certain variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, pattern-matching, trigonometry

Consider a Minimum Working Example,

```
expr = Sin[a] (-I Cos[b] + Sin[b]),
```

is there some way to only apply `TrigToExp[]` for terms containing `b` (for a minimum-working example, output should be: `-I E^(I b) Sin[a]`), leaving other terms untouched? In my actual problem, the expression may be much more complex. I could, for example, apply

```
expr /. {Cos[b] -> TrigToExp[Cos[b]], 
   Sin[b] -> TrigToExp[Sin[b]]} // Simplify
```

and for all other triangular functions (Tan, etc), but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Ummm.... what is MWE?  And why not write it out for those who want to help?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the mwe is to apply TrigToExp only for terms containing `b` in `expr`; reformatted the question to make it easier to read, thanks!

Comment: I have a Mathematica reputation of 18,500 and don't know what the acronym MWE stands for, and suspect at least a few others here don't either.  Why not spell out the three words and be clear?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork thanks for the advice, I saw many just use this phrase for "Minimum Working Example", thought it's a standard here. it's good to be clear :-)

Comment: On the example, `expr /. e : _[b] :> TrigToExp[e]` or `expr /. e_?(FreeQ[a]) :> TrigToExp[e]` seems easiest. Depends on desired output, and whether the variables are known in advance (usually they are, aren't they?).  Use ``expr /. e_?(FreeQ[a | c]) :> TrigToExp[e]` for more variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this suit your needs?

```
expr /. {x_[y_] /; 
    And[MemberQ[{Sin, Cos, Tan, Csc, Sec, Cot}, x], 
        Length[Position[y, b]] > 0]
    :> TrigToExp[x[y]]}
```

Searches for trigonometric functions which contain `b` in their parameters and expands them.

Comment: nice approach using `MemberQ` and `Length[Position[]]`! thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
Replace[expr, h : Except[_[_?(FreeQ[b])]] :> TrigToExp[h], ∞]
```

> -I E^(I b) Sin[a]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another variation, where I inactivate trig functions that don't contain `b`:

```
$trigs = Sin | Cos | Tan | Sec | Csc | Cot;

Activate @ TrigToExp @ ReplaceAll[
    expr,
    (h : $trigs)[x_?(FreeQ[b])] :> Inactive[h][x]
]
```

> -I E^(I b) Sin[a]

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @kglr's method:

```
expr /. h : _[_?(Not@*FreeQ[b])] :> TrigToExp[h]
```

> $\left(-i \left(\frac{e^{-i b}}{2}+\frac{e^{i b}}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} i e^{-i
>    b}-\frac{1}{2} i e^{i b}\right) \sin (a)$